# How to convert Keras .h5 model to darknet yolo.weights format?

Tags: python, keras, yolo

I have trained the yolov2 and yolov3 models using Keras with this Github project https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2

Now I want to use the trained model (.h5) in darknet prediction. Essentially I need to convert this h5 model into the format expected by darknet(.weights). I have seen this project https://github.com/allanzelener/YAD2K/blob/master/yad2k.py

which does the reverse of what I want?
Did anyone try this before?

Comment: Hi, @Karthik were you able to achieve the .h5 model to the Yolo format. Your response will highly be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I also faced but I solved it a bit by using the following code.

```
# Script converter_h5-2-wts.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
''' yolov3_keras_to_darknet.py'''
import argparse
import numpy
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K

def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Darknet\'s yolov3.cfg and         
yolov3.weights \
                                  converted into Keras\'s yolov3.h5!")
    parser.add_argument('-cfg_path', help='yolov3.cfg')
    parser.add_argument('-h5_path', help='yolov3.h5')
    parser.add_argument('-output_path', help='yolov3.weights')
    return parser.parse_args()

class WeightSaver(object):

    def __init__(self,h5_path,output_path):
        self.model = load_model(h5_path)
        self.layers = {weight.name:weight for weight in self.model.weights}
        self.sess = K.get_session()
        self.fhandle = open(output_path,'wb')
        self._write_head()

    def _write_head(self):
        numpy_data = numpy.ndarray(shape=(3,),
                      dtype='int32',
                      buffer=np.array([0,2,0],dtype='int32') )
        self.save(numpy_data)
        numpy_data = numpy.ndarray(shape=(1,),
                      dtype='int64',
                      buffer=np.array([320000],dtype='int64'))
        self.save(numpy_data)

    def get_bn_layername(self,num):
        layer_name = 'batch_normalization_{num}'.format(num=num)
        bias = self.layers['{0}/beta:0'.format(layer_name)]
        scale = self.layers['{0}/gamma:0'.format(layer_name)]
        mean = self.layers['{0}/moving_mean:0'.format(layer_name)]
        var = self.layers['{0}/moving_variance:0'.format(layer_name)]
        bias_np = self.get_numpy(bias)
        scale_np = self.get_numpy(scale)
        mean_np = self.get_numpy(mean)
        var_np = self.get_numpy(var)
        return bias_np,scale_np,mean_np,var_np

def get_convbias_layername(self,num):
    layer_name = 'conv2d_{num}'.format(num=num)
    bias = self.layers['{0}/bias:0'.format(layer_name)]
    bias_np = self.get_numpy(bias)
    return bias_np

def get_conv_layername(self,num):
    layer_name = 'conv2d_{num}'.format(num=num)
    conv = self.layers['{0}/kernel:0'.format(layer_name)]
    conv_np = self.get_numpy(conv)
    return conv_np

def get_numpy(self,layer_name):
    numpy_data = self.sess.run(layer_name)
    return numpy_data

def save(self,numpy_data):
    bytes_data = numpy_data.tobytes()
    self.fhandle.write(bytes_data)
    self.fhandle.flush()

def close(self):
    self.fhandle.close()

class KerasParser(object):

def __init__(self, cfg_path, h5_path, output_path):
    self.block_gen = self._get_block(cfg_path)
    self.weights_saver = WeightSaver(h5_path, output_path)
    self.count_conv = 0
    self.count_bn = 0

def _get_block(self,cfg_path):

    block = {}
    with open(cfg_path,'r', encoding='utf-8') as fr:
        for line in fr:
            line = line.strip()
            if '[' in line and ']' in line:
                if block:
                    yield block
                block = {}
                block['type'] = line.strip(' []')
            elif not line or '#' in line:
                continue
            else:
                key,val = line.strip().replace(' ','').split('=')
                key,val = key.strip(), val.strip()
                block[key] = val

        yield block

def close(self):
    self.weights_saver.close()

def conv(self, block):
    self.count_conv += 1
    batch_normalize = 'batch_normalize' in block
    print('handing.. ',self.count_conv)

    # If bn exists, process bn first, in order of bias, scale, mean, var
    if batch_normalize:
        bias,scale,mean,var = self.bn()
        self.weights_saver.save(bias)
        
        scale = scale.reshape(1,-1)
        mean = mean.reshape(1,-1)
        var = var.reshape(1,-1)
        remain = np.concatenate([scale,mean,var],axis=0)
        self.weights_saver.save(remain)

    # biase
    else:
        conv_bias = self.weights_saver.get_convbias_layername(self.count_conv)
        self.weights_saver.save(conv_bias)

    # weights
    conv_weights = self.weights_saver.get_conv_layername(self.count_conv)
    # (height, width, in_dim, out_dim) (out_dim, in_dim, height, width)
    conv_weights = np.transpose(conv_weights,[3,2,0,1])
    self.weights_saver.save(conv_weights)

def bn(self):
    self.count_bn += 1
    bias,scale,mean,var = self.weights_saver.get_bn_layername(self.count_bn) 
    return bias,scale,mean,var

def main():
    args = parser()
    keras_loader = KerasParser(args.cfg_path, args.h5_path, args.output_path)

    for block in keras_loader.block_gen:
        if 'convolutional' in block['type']:
            keras_loader.conv(block)
keras_loader.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please do the indentation as the code pasted is from text file. I could not leave the four spaces on in the front of the line so please indent the code at your end.
usage is as below

```
$python converter_h5-2-wts.py -cfg_path text.cfg -h5_path test.h5 -output_path test.weights
```

If this works for you please limit vote for this post only but thank the original coder for the source code in python. I just searched some time back for this code.